How do BI tools determine join order when generating SQL?
We are trying to build a self-service reporting tool at work for our bitemporal ledger data (business domain = HR / employee benefits).
For context, we are building vs. using something off-the-shelf because full-fledged BI tools like Tableau, PowerBI, et al are too technical for our user base while semantic layer tools CubeJS and MetricFlow are too simplistic for our data.
However, we are getting stumped on how to order joins (we plan to exclusively left join just like CubeJS and MetricFlow).
Anyone know how BI backends solve this problem?
If it helps, we have already modeled our data with ER diagrams and determined one-to-one, one-to-many, etc relations among tables.
